# How can I find a sublist of a list of length not greater than the third of the length of the list and the sum of the elements of which is maximal

Tags: prolog

How can I find a sublist of a list of length not greater than the third of the length of the list and the sum of the elements  of which is maximal in Prolog?

Comment: Could you be so kind and provide the full text of your homework assignment? It is difficult to understand your interpretation.

Comment: And please show your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't quite enough question here to answer, here is some general advice for tackling this kind of Prolog problem.

You can create lists of specified lengths using `length/2` with an unbound list argument, such as:

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_3192, _3198, _3204].
```

This is often useful when trying to answer questions involving lists. You could take the length of the list and then use `length/2` again to construct the result list.

`select/3` is also a useful predicate for answering these kinds of questions, because it can be used to pick items out of a list. For instance, if I wanted to choose two items from a list, I could do something like this:

```
picktwo(L, [X,Y]) :- select(X, L, L0), select(Y, L0, _).
```

Here I'm just going to return the two items, ignoring the rest of the list which would be available in position I have `_` now.

```
?- picktwo([7,18,3,4,19], X).
X = [7, 18] ;
X = [7, 3] ;
X = [7, 4] ;
X = [7, 19] ;
X = [18, 7] ;
X = [18, 3] ;
X = [18, 4] ;
X = [18, 19] ;
X = [3, 7] ;
X = [3, 18] ;
X = [3, 4] ;
X = [3, 19] ;
X = [4, 7] ;
X = [4, 18] .
```

(DCG fans like myself might be amused by this alternate implementation: `phrase((select(X), select(Y)), [7,18,3,4,19], _).`)

There is a built-in for summing lists, called `sumlist/2`.

Maximizing problems can often be solved in a pretty but highly inefficient way by asking Prolog to find a solution that is larger than all the other solutions. Such code often looks like this:

```
solve(Solution) :- 
   find_solution(Solution), 
   \+ (find_solution(Solution2), Solution2 > Solution1).
```

Here you're declaratively saying that Solution is best because there is no other solution that is better. Prolog will of course have to do the combinatorial thing to find the best solution, so this is definitely turning what may be an O(N log N) search into an O(N^2) search, but it will work okay for small data sets. Here's an example for finding the largest pairs of values:

```
sumpairs(List, X, Y, Sum) :- 
    select(X, List, L0), select(Y, L0, _), Sum is X + Y.

largest(List, X, Y) :- 
    sumpairs(List, X, Y, Sum), 
    \+ (sumpairs(List, _, _, ABSum), ABSum > Sum).
```

This produces:

```
?- largest([7,18,3,4,19], X, Y).
X = 18,
Y = 19 ;
X = 19,
Y = 18 ;
false.
```

So you can see that it is so inefficient it actually found the same answer twice by permutation, but you can probably think of a few ways to prevent that from happening if you care.

This box of parts is probably sufficient for you to find the answer to your problem on your own, good luck!

Comment: DCG fans write `phrase( ( ..., [X], ..., [Y], ... ) , Xs)` thereby avoiding many (most probably) redundant solutions